# How to disable the submit button if page validation fails in ASP.NET using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I need to disable the save button on my form using javascript, if the validation on the page fails. If they don't then it must be enabled used the following code.

*Code:*

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function ValidatePage() 
    {
        if (Page_ClientValidate == true) 
        {

        }

        else 
        {            
            document.getElementById(buttonID).disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
}
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Save" 
  Width="61px" Height="29px" OnClientClick="ValidatePage();" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use ClientID of button, also return true when if statement is true

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
```

You have using Page_ClientValidate as variable but it is function.

*Change*

```
if (Page_ClientValidate == true)
```

*To*

```
if(Page_ClientValidate(""))
```

You are not using the returned value of ValidatingPage() in OnClientClick and as a result you will get postback anyway

*Change*

```
OnClientClick="ValidatePage();"
```

*To*

```
OnClientClick="return ValidatePage();"
```

Comment: It disables the submit button even if the validations are okay, I  used an alert it always goes into the else part of the function eevn if the validations are okay.

Comment: Thank you very much Adil, Thank you for your generosity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick="return ValidatePage();"`

Hope This help.